# Compiling R packages for a memory-profiling configuration

Tags: r, system-administration

Say I have two R installations. Same version but one built for Ubuntu Linux (locally) with memory profiling and the other without. Do I need to compile the installed packages for each separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is 'Nope' as packages are unaffected by this optional feature in the R engine.

If you have particular questions concerning R use on Debian and Ubuntu, come to the r-sig-debian list.